# Separate two values from a large of text, while each of readings separated by a blank line

Tags: text-processing, command-line, json

I've got a peace of large text file with readings like below,

```
name=ABC
class=3
age=7
roll_no=41 

name=XYZ
class=4
age=9
roll_no=23
```

So, how can I separate each `name` with their respective `age` and write the result in a single line, values separated by a space, like this

```
ABC 3
XYZ 9
```

Is there any tool/script to save the result in `JSON` format ?

Tried hours with `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, `grep` etc. etc. but I'm horrible at command line text processing, thanks in advance.

Comment: What should your JSON output look like? Like this: `[{"ABC":7},{"XYZ":9}]` ?

Comment: @glenn, yeah, that'll be fine. or even simpler like this `'{"ABC":7,"XYZ":9}'` , I'll parse it with `jq` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use awk:

```
awk -F"=" '
    {data[$1] = $2} 
    function output() {
        if ("name" in data && "age" in data) 
            print data["name"], data["age"]
        delete data
    }
    NF == 0 {output()} 
    END     {output()}
' filename
```

Comment: That's perfect, I could also modify the output easily, working like a charm with `busybox` inbuilt `awk` . Thank U !

Comment: Sir, could you explain me a bit what's happening step by step ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is available, chunks of text separated by one or more blank lines are perfect for processing with `perl`'s paragraph mode:

```
perl -n00e ' # Read the input file paragraph-by-paragraph
  # Split each paragraph into lines and join the lines with an = sign:
  $s = join "=",split /\n/;
  # Split the joined fields on = signs (with possible blanks around them):
  %h = split /\s*=\s*/,$s;
  print "$h{name} $h{age}\n" # Print the required information
' your_file
```

In the above, the code parses your file into the hash structure (`%h`) where the keys are the field names (on the left of the `=` signs) and the values are the field values (on the right of the `=` signs) on each line. Once the paragraph has been parsed into this structure, we print out the values of the "name" and "age" fields.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly !! Wrote a little shell script for easier parsing, but is there any other solution without using `perl` ?? I want to use something similar in OpenWrt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command:

```
grep -E "name|age" filename | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sed 's/[=,]/ /g'| awk '{ print $2, $4}'
```

it will give output like :

```
ABC 7
XYZ 9
```

EDIT:

Below command will give line which have string `name` or `age`

```
grep -E "name|age" filename

name=ABC
age=7
name=XYZ
age=9
```

This command will make one line of two lines

```
grep -E "name|age" filename | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
name=ABC age=7
name=XYZ age=9
```

Below command will remove equal = sign from output

```
grep -E "name|age" filename | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sed 's/[=,]/ /g'
name ABC age 7
name XYZ age 9
```

Below command printing your requiremnt

```
grep -E "name|age" filename | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sed 's/[=,]/ /g'| awk '{ print $2, $4}'
ABC 7
XYZ 9
```

`awk` printing 2nd and 4th argument of previous command output

still you are facing any problem to understand any syntax google may explain in deep :) .

Comment: Thanks, it's working too, but a bit difficult to understand(for me) what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can understand it better, now I've to learn `sed` basics.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for another language. Here's *one* way to do it in Python, saving the input in a dictionary so that you can easily access the values with the keys `name` and `age`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

myDict = {}

with open("ages") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
       if line == "\n":
            print(myDict['name'].rstrip() + " " + myDict['age'], end="")
            continue
       (key, value) = line.split("=")
       myDict[key] = value

print(myDict['name'].rstrip() + " " + myDict['age'], end="")
```

Given this infile (`ages`):

```
name=ABC
class=3
age=7
roll_no=41

name=XYZ
class=4
age=9
roll_no=23
```

I get this result:

```
./pyAges.py 
ABC 7
XYZ 9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but python a bit heavy on embedded systems, I prefer to use CLI tools.

Comment: @Arnab No problem. You should of course use the solution that is best for you.